# How to find the common chord to $2$ parabolas

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Is there any method to find the common chord of $2$ intersecting parabolas $?$

I was told that equation of common chord of two parabolas is $S_1-S_2$ where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are equations of the parabolas, which does not seems to work in every case. So can any body help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably, you find the two points where the parabolas intersect (assuming there are two such points), and find the equation of the line through those two points.

Comment: You need to find the zeros of S1-S2. Then evaluate S1 at those values. This gives you two distinct points. The segment from one another is the common cord.

Comment: hey jean, firstly thanks for replying so fast. consider a case when S1-S2 does not give the eq. of pair of st. lines(indirectly means that they cannot be factorized) then how will we proceed further??

Answer (score 2):

You would need to start by finding the x-coordinates of their intersections, i.e. the points where $P_1 = P_2$.  In other words, you need to solve the equation $P_1 - P_2 = 0$ which may be where the idea of subtracting the equations came from.  Once you've solved that equation for x, you can use either equation to find the corresponding y values.  At that point, you've got two (x, y) pairs and the equation of the chord will be the equation through those points.

Comment: umm.. i didn't really get what u r saying. i would be happy if u explained with an example. take the parabolas- x=y^2-6y+11 and y=x^2-6x+1 (i have checked on desmos they intersect at 2 points).

Comment: Solve by substitution:  y = (y^2 - 6y + 11)^2 - 6(y^2 - 6y + 11) + 1.  If you solve that equation,  you'll have the y-coordinates of the two points where the parabolas intersect.  That's going to be a fourth degree equation so solving it may be problematic.  I'll leave multiplying out the right hand side and seeing if it factors as an exercise.  Once you've done that, substitute the two real values that you get into the x = y^2 -  6y + 11 equation and you'll get the corresponding x-coordinates.  Now you know where the parabolas intersect.  Find the equation of the line through those points.